# Cakephp Using the id's from a find('list') array instead of display value

Tags: find, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to do this:

```
$customers = $this->Customer->find('list', array('conditions' => //some code));
$conditions = array('Event.customer_id' => $customers //here's the problem);
$this->Event->find('all', ('conditions' => $conditions));
```

the $customers find returns:

```
 array(
       [id1] => "Cust name 1",
       [id2] => "Cust name 2",
       ...
       [idn] => "Cust name n")
```

while I need that in the $conditions the $customers array should be a list of customer id's to find what I need, instead it uses the display value (es. "Cust name n") so the find returns an empty $events variable.

**How is possible to use the array index instead of the array value in a find condition filter?**

I know this could be easy but I'm really stuck here.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to change your code like this:

```
$customers = $this->Customer->find('list', array('conditions' => //filter));
$conditions = array('Event.customer_id' => array_keys( $customers) );
$this->Event->find('all', ('conditions' => $conditions));
```

Notice that you pass `array_keys( $customers )` instead of simply the array. That will extract the IDs you need in a format that CakePHP can use.